# Removing unwanted formatted data from cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I've been struggling with unwanted cell values after adding formulas. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHvVH.png)

This data is being pulled from another sheet. The last column is calculated by =Today()-Cell Value but as soon as the data is cleared, I get a date format in those empty rows. This affects my data viz when pulling data. How do I get empty cells in those empty rows?

Comment: Try `=IF(CellValue="",,Today()-Cell Value)`.

Answer (score 0):

use IF statement. example

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="";;TODAY()-A2:A))
```